# How to create a custom calendar and index through it in Python?

Tags: python, list, datetime, calendar

I want to create a custom calendar in python, still maintains 365 days but has six months. What I want to achieve a program in which the user inputs a date, for example 01/15/2020 and the program would output the date from the custom calendar created. So far I created the custom calendar as a list of tuples like the following:

```
Calendar = [("Leo", range(1, 61)), 
                ("Gemini", range(1, 62)), 
                ("Pegasus", range(1, 62)),
                ("Orion", range(1, 62)),
                ("Scorpius", range(1, 62)),
                ("Taurus", range(1, 62))]
```

Following the example, the first custom month would be "Leo" and it would have 60 days. But I am running into problems iterating through the days for each month. How can I get a specific day of a specific month from this list of tuples? And then how can I relate this to the Gregorian calendar format (ex: January 15th).

I am very new to programming so any help would be grateful! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Get the days past since the year started from the date

```
from datetime import datetime
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
```

Then use a simple if to check where the day falls in a range of 365.

Answer (score 0):

You can currently access a specific day of a specific month like so

```
wanted_month = 'Orion'
wanted_day = 6

for month, days in calendar:           # python allows you to unpack tuples using commas
    if month == wanted_month:
        return month[wanted_day + 1]   # indexes are zero based and your ranges start at 1 so we have to add
```

This could be more performant and simpler if you converted the tuples into a dictionary

```
calendar = {'leo': range(1,61), 'orion': range(61,122)}

calendar[wanted_month][wanted_day + 1]
```

You can convert it into a regular calendar day easily if you know what the day of the year is. So if you wanted the 300th day of the year, you could do this.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime(datetime.datetime.now().year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(300 - 1)
```